# For the Riemann Zeta Function, is there a relation between modulus[Zeta(x+it)] and modulus[Zeta(it)]?

Tags: complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

Graphs of numerical examples show that in the critical strip:                      modulus(Zeta(x+it) < modulus[Zeta(it)].
The question concerns the possibility of generalizing this inequality. 
In "Lectures on the Riemann Zeta Function: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr01.pdf , it was proved that:
Modulus[Zeta(x + it)] < t^(1-e) *[ 1+ 3/e + 1/(1-e)] for x >= e,where  0 < e < 1
since 1/(1-e) > 0, Modulus[Zeta(x + it)] < t^(1-e) *[ 1 + 1/(1-e)]

Therefore: for x = 0, e = 0, Modulus[Zeta(it)] < 2*t 
Hence: Modulus[Zeta(x + it)]/Modulus[Zeta(it)] < 1 since Modulus[Zeta(it)] > 0

Whence: Modulus[Zeta(x + it)] < Modulus[Zeta(it)]

If this reasoning is not correct, is there another way to prove the inequality above?

Thank you

Comment: it was also proven that Modulus[zeta(x+it)] < A(d) t^(1-d) where x > d and 0<d<1. Thus for x = 0, d = 0 and Modulus[Zeta(it)] < t, hence, the inequality: Modulus[zeta(x+it)]  <  Modulus[Zeta(it)]

Comment: do you know the [Lindelöf_hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_hypothesis) ? replace $\zeta(x+it)$ by $\int_0^t |\zeta(x+i\tau)|^2 d\tau$  and you can say something.

Comment: That hypothesis deals with Zeta on the critical line, not modulus[Zeta] as a function of 0 < x < 1 in the critical strip for r = constant. Also, it's a hypothesis/conjecture not a fact. Thank you

Comment: @ Hass : $|\zeta(\sigma+it)| = \mathcal{O}(t^{\scriptstyle\, \mu(\sigma)})$ where $\mu$ is a convex function of $\sigma$ and the Lindelöf hypothesis is that $\mu$ is the smallest possible ([drawn in yellow here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_th.C3.A9orie_de_la_fonction_mu)) so my advice is to [read about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle).

Comment: OK. Will do. Thanks

Comment: Here is what I found:

Comment: Hi. After reading the article you recommended, here is what I found there in addition to the relation above:                                                                       |ζ( it)|= O(t^(1/2)ln^(2/3)| t |  .                                                                     From these two relations, how can it be concluded that :                       |ζ(σ + it)| < |ζ( it)|                                                                                      Thanks

Comment: you need $|\zeta(it)| > f(t)$ or equivalently $|\zeta(1+it)| > g(t)$ and I don't think you'll find something of this kind as on $Re(s) = 1$ : $|\zeta|$ and $|1/\zeta|$ take all the values $]0;\infty[$

Comment: (if I remember well) look at [Titchmarsh's book on the zeta function](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Auteurs/Titchmarsh%20and%20D.%20R.%20Heath-Brown,%20The%20Theory%20of%20the%20Riemann%20Zeta-Function/Titchmarsh%20and%20D.%20R.%20Heath-Brown,%20The%20Theory%20of%20the%20Riemann%20Zeta-Function.pdf) the chapter starting at page 292. and learn latex !!!!

Comment: I'll look it up. Thanks